# How to deploy a Serverless function using Gitlab CI?

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy my Serverless function using a .gitlab-ci.yml file, and to inject environment variables into my function I'm using this format in my serverless.yml file:

```
${file(./serverless.env.yml):${opt:stage, 'dev'}.VARIABLE_1_KEY}
```

My `serverless.env.yml` file looks something like this:

```
staging:
  VARIABLE_1_KEY: xxxxxxx
  VARIABLE_2_KEY: xxxxxxx
  SUBNET_IDS:
    - xxxxxx
    - xxxxxx

production:
  VARIABLE_1_KEY: xxxxxxx
  VARAIBLE_2_KEY: xxxxxxx
  SUBNET_IDS:
    - xxxxxx
    - xxxxxx
```

My issue is that I'm not committing my `serverless.env.yml` file, which means Gitlab won't be able to use it to deploy the function.

I could alter the variables to this format `${env:VARIABLE_KEY}` but this leaves me with the issue where the `SUBNET_IDS` are a list of values and doesn't work when resolving the value from an environment variable.

Is there a better way to define secrets within the project that is compatible with the Gitlab CI process?

Answer (score 0):

To define project level secrets you can go to:

> Your Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables

The secrets will be available via environment variables. You can read more about variables [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)

Regarding your issue with `SUBNET_IDS` list. You can either define each one as a different variable, or you can concat them with a character (, or ; for example) and split them in your script.

Comment: splitting on a special character would work if the variable was being injected into my script, but in this case the variable is being sent directly to AWS which only accepts a list of string.